# if $λ(E) ≥ \epsilon$ then $\int_Efd\lambda\geq \delta$ - proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Assume that $f : [0, 1] \to (0,\infty)$ is a Lebesgue measurable function. Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for every Lebesgue measurable set $E$ with Lebesgue measure $λ(E) ≥ \epsilon$ we have
$$\int_Efd\lambda\geq \delta$$

I tried to do it, but unable to finish the last part . (I tried to write down all the steps to see if there is any part wrong)

My attempt:

let $E = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ where $E_k $ is disjoint subset of $E$. Since $f$ is measurable there exists a non-decreasing sequence of simple function $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \chi_{E_k}$ with $\alpha_k \geq$ converging pointwise to $f$. So using MCT we can write;

$$\int_Efd\lambda = \int_E \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n d\lambda = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_E  S_n d\lambda = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \chi_{E_k} d\lambda $$ $$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \int_0^1\chi_{E_k} d\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k  \lambda (E_k)$$

can I conclude the result using below? (that there exist $\alpha\geq 0 $) such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k  \lambda (E_k) \geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha  \lambda (E_k) =  \alpha \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \lambda (E_k) = \alpha \lambda(E) \geq  \alpha \epsilon = \delta $$

$\textbf{Edit}:$ Is this proof also would work?

suppose by contradiction that $\int_Efd\lambda=0$ , given that $λ(E) ≥ \epsilon$ we would have that $f=0$ a.e. where contradicts the assumpion $f : [0, 1] \to (0,\infty)$ .

Comment: this $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \int_0^1\chi_{E_k} d\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k  \lambda (E_k)$$ is not correctly written because the $\alpha_k$ and the $E_k$ depends on $n$. You must write something like $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{k,n} \int_0^1\chi_{E_{k,n}} d\lambda = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{k,n}  \lambda (E_{k,n})$$

Comment: what about the last part? is it correct?

Comment: no, the rest is not correct. It is possible that such $\alpha$ doesn't exists. I mean: it is possible that $\alpha=0$, so your integral would be zero

Comment: how do I conclude the result? or the proof is totally going no where?

Comment: Egorov's Theorem may be of help to establish that $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @GReyes,  can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to prove by contradiction. Here is a straightforward approach I have in mind. Suppose the conclusion is false. Namely, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall\ \delta>0$, we can find a set $E_\delta\subseteq [0,1]$ with $\lambda(E_\delta)\geq\epsilon$ satisfying 
$$
\int_{E_\delta} f d\lambda<\delta. 
$$
We may choose $\delta = 1/2^n$, for $n = 1, 2, ...$. Then we have construted a sequence $\{E_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ of sets with $\lambda(E_n)\geq\epsilon$, for all $n$, but 
$$
\int_{E_n} f d\lambda<1/2^n.
$$
Now consider $E = \limsup E_n:=\bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{n = k}^\infty E_n$. Specifically, consider $f_k = f\cdot\chi_{\bigcup_{n = k}^\infty E_n}$, $k = 1, 2, ...$, then
$$
\int_{[0,1]} f_k d\lambda\leq \sum_{n = k}^\infty 1/2^n<\infty.
$$
Therefore, $|f_k|=f_k\leq f_1=|f_1|$ with $f_1$ Lebesgue integrable and $f_k\to f\cdot \chi_E$ pointwisely. By dominated convergence theorem, 
$$
\int_E f = \int \lim_{k\to\infty} f_k = \lim_{k\to\infty}\int f_k=0.
$$
But $\lambda(E)\geq\epsilon$ and $f$ is nonnegative. This means $f = 0$ a.e. on $E$, contradicting to $f>0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: how you deduced that $\lambda(E)\ge \epsilon$? What I see is that $E\subset E_k$ for infinitely many $k$

Comment: Defining $F_k = \bigcup_{n = k}^\infty E_n$, we have $F_k\downarrow E$. Since $\lambda(F_k)\geq\epsilon$, $\lambda(E)\geq\epsilon$. (This follows from "countable additivity" of measure or dominated convergence theorem with sequence of characteristic functions.)

Comment: The property is called "continuity from above". You may find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above